# Не выводятся данные из mysql в TreeView

Tags: python, tkinter, mysqli

Всем привет.
При вводе в поле введите фамилию не выводятся данные в виджет TreeView ошибок тоже нет не пойму в чем дело.
Подскажите в чем проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter  as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql


def Bysearch(): # triggered on Button Click
    #lab2.config(text=cal.get_date())
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    yourname = textbox.get()
    yourdate = cal.get_date()
    cursor.execute("SELECT  * from base WHERE  fio LIKE %s and data = %s", (yourname + '%', yourdate))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        tree.insert('',0,text="",values=(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]))



mydb = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="******",database="scud" )

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("СКУД ")
root.geometry("800x600")

#Отображение поля фамилии
lab=Label(root,text = "Введите Фамилию ")
lab.place(x = 30, y = 20,width = 200, height = 25)

#Ввод в окно фамилии
textbox = Entry(text = "")
textbox.place(x = 33, y = 40, width = 200, height = 25)

#Виджет календарь
#variable = StringVar()
cal = DateEntry(root,width=20,bg="darkblue",fg="white",selectmode='day')
cal.grid()

cal.place(x = 300, y = 40,width = 200, height = 25)
# Кнопка Найти
button = Button(root,text = "Найти",command=Bysearch())
button.place(x = 560, y = 40, width = 200, height = 25)

columns = ( 'fio', 'data', 'time', 'value')
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=columns)
tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tree.column('fio',width =50,minwidth=10,anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('data',width =50,minwidth=10,anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('time',width =50,minwidth=10,anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('value',width =50,minwidth=10,anchor=CENTER)


tree.heading('fio',text='Фамилия',anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('data',text='Дата',anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('time',text='Время',anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('value',text='Приход Уход',anchor=CENTER)

tree.grid()
tree.place(x = 30, y = 100,width = 730, height = 450)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Кнопка Найти
button = Button(root,text = "Найти",command=Bysearch)
```

И все работает